# How does this solution of Project Euler Problem 27 in the Haskell Wiki work?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, math, functional-programming

I have been solving some random Project Euler problems to practice my haskell. After solving the problem, I usually look up the [solution](https://wiki.haskell.org/Euler_problems/) on the haskell wiki.

For [Problem 27](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=27), I solved it the regular way, i.e, using a combination of `isPrime` and `map`s. But then, I saw this solution on the wiki. I have no idea how this solution works. The only other mention I find of it is from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881544/computing-question-a-quadratic-which-gives-primes) closed thread on math stackexchange.

```hs
problem_27 :: Integer
problem_27 = -(2 * a - 1) * (a ^ 2 - a + 41)
  where
    n = 1000
    m = head $ filter (\x -> x ^ 2 - x + 41 > n) [1 ..]
    a = m - 1
```

##### My attempt at understanding this code

As I understand, this code does the following

1. Let n=1000
2. Let m be the first natural number x, such that x^2 - x + 41 is greater than n(here 1000)
3. Then a = m - 1
4. The answer to the problem is -(2a-1) * (a^2-a+41): (I think that this means that the two are the coefficients.)

But I do not understand why this program gives the correct answer. Or in other words, **What is the reasoning behind this algorithm?**

Comment: Does it in fact produce the right answer? The problem appears to ask for two numbers, while this expression of course yields only one.

Comment: @amalloy Yes this is the correct answer. Note that the requirement is for the product of the two coefficients, which will result in a single number. I have confirmed it with other solutions on the internet as well.

Comment: I think this is more of a question for [maths.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/), not for StackOverflow.

Comment: A cryptic solution indeed. Maybe the same algorithm was also used in other languages, and maybe some one while writing a solution in these other languages wrote why this actually works. (Whishful thinking, but...) Perhaps you could try searching for solutions in other languages?

Comment: Note that `n^2 + n + 41` gives prime values for all `n` between `-40` and `39` (inclusive). That means that for any integer `x`, `(n - x)^2 + (n - x) + 41` gives prime values for all `n` between `x - 40` and `x + 39`. So e.g., with `x = 5` you get prime outputs for `-35` through `44`, so we get 45 prime outputs if we start at `0`. The code is simply finding the largest `x` that doesn't overflow the required bounds on `a` and `b`. This is the easy part of the reasoning. The hard part is reasoning that there's no other polynomial that will do better; that's where the number theory comes in.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks! That is all I needed. But I do not understand the multiplication here. What is the significance of the two expressions chosen? About the rest, I will try to figure out a proof, and if I do, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

```
(n-x)^2 + a(n-x) + b = n^2 + (a-2x)n + x^2 - ax + b
```

which means that a change of variables can turn any (integer-coefficient) quadratic into one of the forms n^2+d or n^2+n+d with a judicious choice of x. Now the first form is no good: every other term is even, so we can't have a long run of primes. For quadratics of the second form, Rabinowitz proved that the quadratic that produces the maximum sequence of primes must have 4d-1 a [Heegner number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number), of which there are only 6. It's quick from there to check that n^2+n+41 is the best of those six, and the next best, n^2+n+17, produces fewer consecutive primes total (i.e. both positive and negative inputs) than n^2+n+41 does starting at 0.

Now, (-1-n)^2+(-1-n)+41 = n^2+n+41, so if n produces a prime, then -1-n does, too. This means about half the consecutive primes produced by this quadratic are produced by a negative input, so the more of those we can shift into range without blowing our coefficient budget, the better; and, what's more, we can't do better than trying to shift in more values, because shifting any other polynomial around gets fewer consecutive primes than before we even shift this one.

What is our budget? Well, looking back at our very first equation, now with a=1 and b=41, we must have:

```
|1-2x| < 1000
|x^2-x+41| < 1000
```

because these are the final two coefficients. The second is going to be our limiter, since x^2 generally grows much faster than 2x, so we are simply looking for the largest x that validates that equation. This is what the

```
m = head $ filter (\x -> x ^ 2 - x + 41 > n) [1 ..]
a = m-1
```

snippet does. Once we have that, 1-2x and x^2-x+41 are our two coefficients, and we want to compute their product, which is what the

```
-(2 * a - 1) * (a ^ 2 - a + 41)
```

snippet does.